# Rails - in which action is created the new user with Devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, controller, action

I am using Devise and when I check the form for registration of the new user, in the method is set up just this: `/users`.

When I check in logs where the app goes after hitting submit button in the registration form, it's here:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-21 18:13:11 +0200
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
```

But when I go to the `Registration Controller` and there to the action `create` and comment all code in there, there is no error, everything is processed correctly, which makes me confused.

Where is the code for creating a new user for Devise gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom RegistrationController is built for overwrite the original one when needed.

If you remove all custom code, the original controller in gem will be called. It has already been included into app when loading.

Here is the code for original one: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

To correctly overwrite, you need to specify it in routes.rb.

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'users/registrations',
                                   sessions: 'users/sessions' }
```

Then, create file `app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb`.

Then, name this class with namespace as defined in routes, and inherit it from original controller

```
class Users::RegistrationController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    if foo == bar
      # your logic
    else
      super # Call original method
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It looks like my `RegistrationController ` is ignored... because the code I put there is not processed... how to overwrite the default one?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to figure out the issue!